# Self learning on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Currently I'm trying to understand and learn new code commands for vb.net. i have came across three codes while researching which is

```
"SELECT staff_id,pass_word FROM userlogin WHERE staff_id = @staff_id AND pass_word = @pass_word")
```

Second code:

```
Dim uName As New OleDbParameter("@staff_id", SqlDbType.VarChar)
```

Third and last:

```
uName.Value = txtstaffid.Text
myCommand.Parameters.Add(uName)
```

What are the uses of `@pass_word` code when you have already typed the pass_word column, Oledbparameter, and Parameters.Add?

Comment: This is a bad practice for what you're looking at. But the gist of this is, the programmer wants a row result from the database containing staff_id and pass_word but only if those two match what the user inputs. So if it doesn't find a row then one or the other was wrong making the login unsuccessful. as far as bad practice, there is no need to bring a password into your code.  Due to space constraints in this comment I'll just say: You should hash the user's input and see if that hash is stored in the database for that user for a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows a bit more complete picture of what the code is doing. The Using...End Using blocks ensure that your objects are closed and disposed even if there are errors. Of course, in a real application, passwords would never be stored as plain text (too easy to hack). They would be salted and hashed but that is for another day.

```
Private Sub CheckPassword()
        'This line assigns a Transact SQL command to a string variable.
        'It will return a record with 2 columns. The @staff_id and @pass_word are parameter placeholders.
        'The use of parameters limits the possibilit of SQL injection with malicious input be the user
        'typing in the text box.
        Dim strSQL = "SELECT staff_id,pass_word FROM userlogin WHERE staff_id = @staff_id AND pass_word = @pass_word;"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            'Pass the command string and the connection to the constructor of the command.
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
                'It is unneccessary to create a command variable.
                'The .Add method of the commands Parameters collection will create a parameter.
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@staff_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtstaffid.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass_word", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    'All we really need to know is whether we returned a row.
                    If dr.HasRows Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful")
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed")
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ctznkane525 , absolutely agreed. I thought I covered that in my opening paragraph. I guess your comment was for emphasis or I was not clear. Thanks.